# Which route will be selected?

Tags: networking, ip, route

I was confused by `ip route list` output on linux box.
He is shows route:

```
172.30.0.0/16 via 117.158.54.60 dev ppp0  src 192.168.200.1
```

I read in manual

> the source address to prefer when sending to the destinations covered
>   by the route prefix.

Ok, but if packets will be sending from `192.168.200.1` ip it shouldn't sending from `ppp0` via `117.158.54.60` ip.

Yes, dev `ppp0` has `117.158.54.60` as next hop, BUT `192.168.200.1` it is an `eth0` device ip. So actually which device will be preferred `eth0` or `ppp0` to send packets to `172.30.0.0/16` network? I am don't understand why `ip` utility have accept this "2 devices route" command.

P.S. `ppp0` it is isp connection, but isp twisted-pair connected to `eth1` card.

Please help me with it.

My route table:

```
117.158.54.60 dev ppp0  proto kernel  scope link  src 117.158.54.31
57.182.238.104 dev ppp0  scope link  src 117.158.54.31  mtu 1492
44.226.203.71 dev ppp0  scope link
192.168.200.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.200.1
172.20.41.0/24 via 5.5.0.1 dev tun0  metric 101
172.20.20.0/23 via 5.5.0.1 dev tun0  metric 101
172.20.30.0/23 via 5.5.0.1 dev tun0  metric 101
5.5.0.0/21 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 5.5.0.106
5.5.0.0/20 via 5.5.0.1 dev tun0  metric 101
172.30.0.0/16 via 117.158.54.60 dev ppp0  src 192.168.200.1
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1004
192.168.0.0/16 dev tun1  scope link
10.208.0.0/12 dev tun1  scope link
10.176.0.0/12 dev tun1  scope link
default dev ppp0  scope link
```

Comment: I don't undestand `2 devices route`. Can you show all ip routes and ip addresses?

Comment: I mean that dev ppp0 it is one device and 192.168.200.1 it is another device (eth0). While route mean as i know always one device specified to send packets from to destined network.

Comment: No. You can have two or .more same route rules which have different outgoing interfaces and different priority.

Comment: But here is one rule contain 2 outgoing interfaces. P.S. i have update question with my route table.

Answer (score 0):

You have only one IP network which has two route rules:

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth1  scope link  metric 1002
169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1004
```

169.254.0.0/16 is the special IP block for link-local addressing. See a documentation at [Zero-configuration networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking)

To disable link-local (zeroconf) on Debian-like Linux set `AVAHI_DAEMON_DETECT_LOCAL=0` in `/etc/default/avahi-daemon` configuration file.

To disable link-local (zeroconf) on RedHat-like Linux set `NOZEROCONF=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` configuration file.

Reboot will apply new configuration (or restart network or avahi services).

Comment: No you dont understand me. Please re read question. I mean route `172.30.0.0/16 via 117.158.54.60 dev ppp0 src 192.168.200.1` it tell that packets should be send from dev `ppp0` right? Ok but at the end src tell that packets send from `192.168.200.1` which belong to `eth0` interface. How it can be?

Comment: I think you use `iproute2`. Then show output of command `ip route show table all`.

Comment: It is not matter, `ip route show table all` shows the same route.

Comment: I think you still don't understand. "How in one route rule can be 2 output devices: ppp0 and eth0?"

Comment: Enyone have idea more?

Comment: If this route isn't assigned statically it come dynamically from your provider via ppp connection.

Comment: Are you sure that understand my question? How this route come is known. From ipsec service. Question is another. How in one route rule can be 2 output devices: ppp0 and eth0?